# Losing part of wordpress post content on saving {clicking Update}

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I open a post for editing and click on the `update button`  to reflect the changes, I end up losing a section of the post. I am running the latest version of wordpress `wordpress 3.5`

Any hints on where I can start debugging for the issue or is this a bug with the `wordpress 3.5` version. I haven't encountered this error on any of the previous releases.

Comment: Start by disabling all of your plugins.

Comment: How much of the post are you losing?  From the start?  From the end? Are you using more links?  Are you using plugins?  Are the plugins compatible with 3.5?  Jquery went from 1.7 to 1.8 and could possibly an issue if you rely on jQuery.

Comment: I'm losing almost everything after the 1st paragraph.

Comment: Are you using a more tag? Posting the link to your site would help.

Comment: Using the <!--more--> tag has the same effect. However, I tried just editing a post and clicking Update to save it. I end up losing most of the content after the 1st / 2nd <p> tags  / paragraphs

Comment: Are  you pasting content from an external editor? Word, maybe?